# xcodebuild clean failed - for a nonexistant scheme?

Tags: xcode, continuous-integration, xcodebuild, xcode-workspace

I'm currently configuring a Continuous Integration job for my workplace. I've run into some issues, that I hope you can help me with.

It starts like this.

```
[Info] Loading settings for scheme 'SPONTAN' ... (1764 ms)

=== CLEAN ===

xcodebuild clean SPONTAN
Pods / Pods-ActionSheetPicker-3.0 (Debug)
  ~ Check dependencies (9 ms)
  ~ Remove libPods-ActionSheetPicker-3.0.a (7 ms)
  ~ Remove Pods-ActionSheetPicker-3.0.build (5 ms)
  0 errored, 0 warning (13 ms)

Pods / Pods-ABPadLockScreen (Debug)
  0 errored, 0 warning (13 ms)

~ Check dependencies (10 ms)
~ Remove libPods-ABPadLockScreen.a (7 ms)
~ Remove Pods-ABPadLockScreen.build (5 ms)
Pods / Pods-Bolts (Debug)
  0 errored, 0 warning (12 ms)
```

...

```
SPONTAN / SPONTAN (Debug)
      ~ Check dependencies (80 ms)
      ~ Create product structure (0 ms)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/bin/mkdir -p /b/d20150508-639-140oy5t/zios/ABVfrRTRd5bE2Fty/SPONTAN.app
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      ~ Remove SPONTAN.app (1 ms)
      ~ Remove SPONTAN-Prefix.pch.pch (1 ms)
      ~ Remove SPONTAN-Prefix.pch.pch (0 ms)
      ~ Remove SPONTAN.app.dSYM (0 ms)
      ~ Remove SPONTAN.build (0 ms)
      0 errored, 0 warning (83 ms)


  xcodebuild build clean
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Scheme Tests is not currently configured for the clean action.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------


** CLEAN FAILED ** (2937 ms)
```

It says the clean of a scheme called Tests is not configured. Now I've been looking for a scheme called Tests for an hour without success. Is there any way to fix this? I've set all Schemes to have Shared enabled and autocreate schemes is disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by enabling Analyze, Test, Profile on my CI scheme.